# Let $\mathbb H$ be algebra of quaternions and let $S$ be the group of unit quaternions. What does it mean for a point to be tangent to $\mathcal S$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> Let $\mathbb H$ be the algebra of quaternions and let $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb H$ be the group of unit quaternions.
>
> Show that if $p \in \mathbb H$ is imaginary, then $qp$ is tangent to $\mathcal S$ at each $q \in \mathcal S$.

**Definition**: If $S$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$, and $p \in S$, a vector field $X: M \to TM$ is tangent to $S$ at $p$ if $X(p) \in T_p S \subset T_p M$.

What does it mean for a point, like $qp$, to be tangent to $\mathcal S$?

Comment: Please edit the title. $\Bbb H^\times$ is *not* the group of unit quaternions.

Comment: As it always the case with a sphere centered at the origin, any vector $v$ is tangent to the sphere at $p$ iff the two vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: @TedShifrin I didn't know. I though $A^\times$ was always the group of units of $A$. What is $\mathbb H^\times$?

Comment: That's for a ring, but this is a (non-commutative) field, so the units are all the nonzero elements. *Unit quaternions* means those on the unit sphere $p\bar p = 1$.

Comment: The title is still (equivalently) wrong. You're not understanding the use of *unit*, as I explained.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yea, I'm not understanding. Why are the unit quaternions on the unit sphere $p\bar p =1$?

Comment: Is it just quaternions with length one?

Comment: @TedShifrin As far as I know, field is a commutative division ring, so is there such a thing as "non-commutative field"? $\mathbb H$ is a division algebra as stated in Lee's Intro. to Smooth Manifolds (2nd edition) pg.173.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{H}$ is a vector space, the tangent space at each point of $\mathbb{H}$ can be canonically identified with $\mathbb{H}$ itself.  So, when it says $qp$ is tangent to $\mathcal{S}$ at $q$, this means that $qp$, considered as a tangent vector to $\mathbb{H}$ at the point $q$, is in the tangent space of the submanifold $\mathcal{S}$.